# QT creator horizontal spin box

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

Is there a way to create a QSpinBox whose arrows point left and right (rather than up and down)? I haven't been able to find anything about this, even though it seems quite basic.

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want, I can think of several types of spinbox with your description.

Comment: Yes, strange they didn't implement it! even I thought of a way to flip it 90 degrees! but looked funny!

Answer (score 4):

You can move the buttons to the control sides, and give them custom arrow bitmaps using a stylesheet like this:

```
QSpinBox::down-button  {
  subcontrol-origin: margin;
  subcontrol-position: center left;
  image: url(:/icons/leftArrow.png);
}

QSpinBox::up-button  {
  subcontrol-origin: margin;
  subcontrol-position: center right;
  image: url(:/icons/rightArrow.png);
}
```

As an example, apply the following stylesheet to a spinbox with fixed height of 26 pixels:

```
QSpinBox {
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

QSpinBox::up-button  {
  subcontrol-origin: margin;
  subcontrol-position: center left;
  image: url(:/icons/leftArrow.png);
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  left: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

QSpinBox::down-button  {
  subcontrol-origin: margin;
  subcontrol-position: center right;
  image: url(:/icons/rightArrow.png);
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  right: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

to obtain this:

[image: styled spinbox]

Comment: Im not familiar, looks like PyQt ?

Comment: In your second example, down=right and up=left, that's not expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you know that qt do not provide it directly.
Look into below documentation, it has three options.

```
QAbstractSpinBox::UpDownArrows
QAbstractSpinBox::PlusMinus
QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#ButtonSymbols-enum

**But you can style the spin box** using style sheet properties using desired images.

Come up with good image files for left and right symbols and set the image files using stylesheets as shown below.

```
QSpinBox::up-button { image: url(:/images/spinRight.png) }
QSpinBox::down-button { image: url(:/images/spinLeft.png) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found Qt native solution, so try do it with some tricks, one possible raw example below, the basic idea is to make the Spinbox bare (no native buttons, and make your own buttons)  `setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons);`, I used just simple text for left/right button, you can choose a more fancy images for the buttons:

.h

```
//


private slots:
    void leftBtn();
    void RightBtn();

private:
    QSpinBox *spinBx;
//
```

.cpp

```
{
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QToolButton *btnLt = new QToolButton;
    btnLt->setText("<"); // this is simple, use your image to style the button
    QToolButton *btnRt = new QToolButton; // or could be pushbutton!
    btnRt->setText(">");
    spinBx = new QSpinBox;
    spinBx->setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons);
    hlayout->addWidget(btnLt);
    hlayout->addWidget(spinBx);
    hlayout->addWidget(btnRt);
    connect(btnLt, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::leftBtn);
    connect(btnRt, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::RightBtn);

    this->ui->centralWidget->setLayout(hlayout);
}

 void MainWindow::leftBtn()
{
    this->spinBx->setValue(this->spinBx->value()-1);
}
void MainWindow::RightBtn()
{
    this->spinBx->setValue(this->spinBx->value()+1);
}
```